# ftp disconnects on 'get' command?

Tags: ftp

This just started today, after an organization-wide network outage, the nature of which has still not been explained.

ftp connect from my workstation (Win7 Pro) to various Linux servers works, until I try to actually 'get' a file:

```
C:\temp>ftp <myserver>
Connected to <myserver>.<myorg>.org.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
User (<myserver>.<myorg>.org:(none)): oracle
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
ftp> cd <mydir>
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> binary
200 Switching to Binary mode.
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> get <myfile>.zip
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
425 Failed to establish connection.
ftp>
```

From the 'get' command, the '200' message appears instantly, and then there is a delay of 60 seconds before the '425' message.

Looking for additional info or questions I can take to the network admin guy.

Comment: Poosible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516263/200-port-command-successful-consider-using-pasv-425-failed-to-establish-connec

Comment: Possible duplicate of [200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV. 425 Failed to establish connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516263/200-port-command-successful-consider-using-pasv-425-failed-to-establish-connec)

Comment: Ok, I see that the question was "answered" elsewhere. Sort of.  First, PASV is not supported by the ftp client on Win7.  Second, this is a batch process that has been working for several years, and the problem just manifested itself after a corporate-wide network issue, so it is not something inherent in my script.

Comment: FWIW, after rebooting my own desktop, the problem cleared itself.  I guess this will just have to go down as an unsolved mystery.