# 200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV. 425 Failed to establish connection (Windown Laptop)

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-16.04, ftp-client

I set up FTP server in Ubuntu Server.

But i can not upload file to my ftp server from Window laptop. (Althought Mac is ok)

This is my content in /etc/vsftpd.conf file

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

And what i tried in my Windown Laptop.

```
ftp> open 188.166.238.68
Connected to 188.166.238.68.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (188.166.238.68:vubuivn): phuclongcms
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
230 Login successful.
ftp> cd files
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> put vnhconnect.pem 
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
425 Failed to establish connection.
ftp>
```

In Mac laptop, i can use syntax "passive" before upload files. And i'm able to upload file. But Windown laptop, i can not.

I tried to follow many anwsers in stackoverflow. But it was not work.

Thank you

Comment: What *"many anwsers in stackoverflow"* did you follow? What did you try? – Did you see [200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV. 425 Failed to establish connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19516263/850848#28832663)?