# Getting "I won't open a connection to" when connecting to FTP server from Google Compute Engine

Tags: linux, ftp, connection, debian, google-compute-engine

I ssh'ed to my Google Compute Engine's VM. And want to ftp to another server from there. It asked my username and password, I could login without problem. But when I do `ls` or `get`, I receive this error:

```
500 I won't open a connection to 10.240.XX.XX (only to XX.XX.XX.XX)
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

That 10.240.XX.XX is my internal IP address I saw in `ifconfig` result.

How can I transfer files from another server using FTP?
System: Debian7

Answer (score 86):

You are using the active mode of FTP to connect to a server running Pure-FTPd. In the active mode, a server has to connect back to a client to open a data transfer connection (for file transfers or directory listing). For that, the client sends its IP address to the FTP server in the `PORT` command.

If the FTP server is outside of the GCE private network, it obviously cannot connect back to the client machine, as the machine is behind a firewall and NAT.

And actually the Pure-FTPd explicitly checks that the IP address in the `PORT` command matches the client IP address of the FTP control connection. It won't match, if the client sends its internal IP address within the GCE network. If this case, the Pure-FTPd server rejects the transfer outright (without even trying to connect) with the error message, you are getting:

> I won't open a connection to ... (only to ...)

*(where the first `...` is the IP address provided by the client in the `PORT` command [the local address within the GCE private network), and the second `...` is the external [NATed] IP address of the client, as known by the server).*

---

Even if the client reported the external [NATed] address in the `PORT` command, it still won't work as the connection attempt won't get past the NAT and firewall.

For this reason, the passive FTP mode exists, in which the client connects to the server to open the data transfer connection. Actually, none uses the active mode nowadays.

See (my article) [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details about the modes.

So, switch to the passive mode. How this is done is client-specific.

- In most common *nix `ftp` command-line clients, use the `-p` command-line switch, though the passive mode is used by default anyway:

  > `-p`    Use passive mode for data transfers. Allows use of ftp in environments where a firewall prevents
  > connections from the outside world back to the client machine. Requires that the ftp server sup-
  > port the PASV command. This is the default now for all clients (ftp and pftp) due to security
  > concerns using the PORT transfer mode.  The flag is kept for compatibility only and has no effect
  > anymore.
- Some clients also support `passive` command.
- If you are on Windows, you cannot use the built-in command-line `ftp.exe` client, as it does not support the passive mode at all. You have to install a third-party client. See [How to use passive FTP mode in Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/850848)

Comment: This was my problem too; apparently, not all Linux ftp clients use passive mode by default.

Comment: Note for anyone on Windows who has this problem (I realise this question isn't about Windows, but I was and I arrived here by searching for "_I won't open a connection to_"): according to [How to use passive FTP mode in Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/2096401) and its answers, the _native_ FTP client of Windows (even up to 10) does not support passive mode, so an alternative would be needed (answers to that question mention WinSCP).

Answer (score 42):

Enable your FTP with passive mode, if you have already connected please type

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
```

You are currently using FTP in passive mode.

Comment: As a note - passive is a boolean that will toggle between passive mode and active mode in ftp.  This can be confusing for those who haven't switched modes before.

Answer (score 1):

if you use wsl2 linux subsystem in windows 10:use
pftp

Answer (score -1):

If you use PsPad editor and you have the same issue, try to set this configuration for your connection:

[image]

Comment: What is *"this configuration"*? Please describe it in words, not just using a screenshot.

Comment: It's not just a screenshot as you see, I wrote that this is the way to set your connection to work, I had  this problem and I did not found the solution anywhere, I found it today by my self and I wanted to help others not to waist their time like I did.

Comment: [Are screenshots useful in answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287829/850848) - *"There is nothing wrong with posting a screenshot to show users how something works, **so long as the screenshot is accompanied by textual information that explains the same thing in words**"*

Comment: I am not a system admin, I can't say why it works like this and it does not work in other way. The only thing is that for me it worked with this settings and I wanted others to benefit from this.If you consider that they should do the search for their own, it's not a problem for me, I will simply delete the answer.

Comment: Sure! Just write, *"check the option XXX to make it work"*. There is dozen options on the screenshot. How do we know what is the *magical* one?

Comment: I tried all of the options, I used SSL/TLS, Also the Prot P setting, I've checked MLDS with and without the show hidden file because some said that servers might have a problem with the hidden setting. I've checked the Prox Server also and the ones that are checked now. Finally I don't know why this configuration works, but this works and I also can't know for sure if there is a magical checkbox checked. I started with no checkboxes selected. (and I had the same issue at the begining)

Comment: Then, it was the *"Passive mode"* option. If could not work, with the option unchecked.

Comment: I have 8 websites, on some of them I use the SSL/TLS option and it works with that, but now when I had this issue I had passive mode selected but it wasn't working. One reasone was because I had the "Use SSL/TLS if available" checked.