# Upload text file to Google uploads via PHP FTP PUT

Tags: php, upload, ftp, port, google-shopping-api

I am trying to upload a text file that is created from a database via PHP.

The text file is created OK, but when I try and upload the file via PHP FTP Put it fails.

My code:

```
$filename = "products_admin.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
fwrite($handle, $content);
fclose($handle);
echo "Attempting to connect to <i>uploads.google.com</i>...<br />";
$ftp_connect = ftp_connect("uploads.google.com", "21", "5000") or die("failed to connect.");
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connect, "{usernamehere}", "{passwordhere}") or die("ERROR: Username or Password incorrect.");

if((!$ftp_connect) || (!$login_result)) {
    echo "ERROR: Couldn't connect to <i>uploads.google.com</i>, upload failed.<br /><br />";
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:location.reload(true)\">Try Again</a>";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected to <i>uploads.google.com</i>...<br />";
    $upload = ftp_put($ftp_connect, $filename, $filename, FTP_ASCII);
    if(!$upload) {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to upload ".$filename." to <i>uploads.google.com</i>.<br /><br />";
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:location.reload(true)\">Try Again</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Uploading <i>".$filename."</i> to <i>Froogle</i>...<br />";
        echo "Successfully uploaded <i>".$filename."</i> to <i>uploads.google.com</i>.<br /><br />";
        echo "Done.";
    }
}
ftp_close($ftp_connect);
```

The error message I get is

Warning: ftp_put(): PORT IP is not same as 176.32.230.48. in /home/sites/mysite.co.uk/public_html/admin/controllers/generate_feed.php on line 100 ERROR: Failed to upload products_admin.txt to uploads.google.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably just need to activate passive mode:

```
...
$login_result = ftp_login($ftp_connect, "{usernamehere}", "{passwordhere}") or die("ERROR: Username or Password incorrect.");
ftp_pasv($ftp_connect, true);
...
```

Comment: One note from the comments section in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php):  _If you are still having problems after choosing ftp_pasv() you should refresh the connection through ftp_close() / ftp_connect() after x files and/or y GB have been transfered._

Answer (score 0):

When I used FTP with my Google Compute Engine server, I had the same problem which occured because server is behind Google's firewall. You can read more about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226143/failed-to-ftp-upload-using-windows-ftp-exe-port-ip-is-not-same-as-nnn-nnn-nnn). You can try enabling passive mode which doesn't care about IP with function [ftp_pasv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ftp-pasv.php).