# send command to existing cmd shell

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-console

I'm trying to create a script to log into something similar to ftp, but it does not use ftp commands. I'm thinking of trying a batch file or Python solution.

Manually it's done through a cmd shell as follows:

```
C:\Users..etc>
passiveftp 123.45.67.890 #connects to ftp in passive mode
#then asks for username and you don't see 'C:\Users..etc.' anymore
Connceted to 123.45.67.890
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)

User name:
#here you'd enter user name, then password, then start dl/ul'ing
```

For a standard ftp connection, I found that you can use a separate text file with each input and then just run the following command:

```
ftp -s:filename.txt
```

But it looks like this ftp program does not accept that. I tried it with the following text file:

```
passiveftp 123.45.67.890
usernamehere
passwordhere
hash
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
C:\Users\etc.>passiveftp -s:filename.txt
ftp> Invalid command.
ftp> Invalid command.
ftp> Invalid command.
ftp> Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark).
ftp>
```

Is there a way to automate this scenario like what can be done with ftp commands?

Comment: Have considered running `passiveftp` via Python's `subprocess.Popen` and piping the sequence of commands to stdin, with CRLF line endings? That should work in most cases, unless the program insists on reading input directly from the console.

Comment: Have a look at [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The [API Overview](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) shows how to control an FTP session. You should be able to adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: It appears that PASV mode can be used with the Microsoft provided ftp.exe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643542/how-to-use-passive-ftp-mode-in-windows-command-prompt Is there some other reason that you must use a different FTP program?

Comment: @eryksun with something like `subprocess.Popen(["start", "/wait", "cmd", "/c", "passiveftp address"+"\r"+"\n", "username"+"\r"+"\n", "password"+"\r"+"\n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` a window appears and `passiveftp address` works, but it's the same as before where the username isn't entered. is that the correct use of CRLF?

Comment: You don't need the shell, and the input should be written to stdin. for example: `p = subprocess.Popen(["passiveftp",  address], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0);` `p.stdin.write(b"username\r\npassword\r\n");`. Eventually you can send it a command to quit, or just kill it with `p.kill()`.

Comment: do you know why `p = subprocess.Popen(["passiveftp", address], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)` opens a window that crashes the program? "FTP command-line tool has stopped working" i've never used bufsize before, is it that?

Comment: No, `bufsize` is to disable buffering for `p.stdin` in Python. It has nothing to do with the child process. It could be crashing because `stdin` is a pipe.

Comment: @eryksun does `p = subprocess.Popen(["passiveftp", address], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)` do the same thing as opening a command prompt and typing `passiveftp address` in the default directory? it was crashing before because i changed the directory earlier and was in the wrong one. now it is saying `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified` when i start a new python idle and try

Comment: In cmd it's more like running `(echo username & echo password) | passiveftp address`. But there's no cmd shell involved. It runs `passiveftp` directly with its stdin connected to a pipe, and on the other end of the pipe you have `p.stdin` to which you write the byte string `b"username\r\npassword\r\n"`. If you need to set the working directory, use the `cwd` argument of `Popen`, e.g. `cwd=r'C:\Temp'`.

Comment: with cwd set to the location of passiveftp.exe or the default directory of my cmd prompt window, i still get the same error.. passiveftp.exe is in `..windows\system32`, is that why it works in cmd? can it be emulated through `Popen`?

Comment: Have you tried `p = subprocess.Popen(["passiveftp", address])` without `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, to determine whether the pipe is causing the problem? Don't try to use `p.stdin` in this case since it's not set to a pipe. It should open in a new console and prompt for the username and password.

Comment: okay, yes. without `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` a console prompting for user name appears

Comment: When you run `passiveftp` from cmd, does it run in the same console window? Or does it open a new window that just looks like the Windows console?

Comment: @eryksun yes, the same console window. it looks similar to how it works with an ftp connection. the default dir shown when you first open the window goes away and the 'ui (i guess)' changes to the passiveftp 'ui'

Comment: @DavidCullen is the download for python 2.7 discontinued or canceled?

Comment: @lit i see complaints about winscp being slow. is there a way to get the average speed of a download or upload via winscp?

Comment: @baconpancakes: I [install pexpect via pip](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html). Please note that [pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows) must be used on Windows.

Comment: @DavidCullen it looks like `pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn` does not have an `interact()` method, so i'm trying to make a basic one.. i tried this, but the console crashes after the `raw_input()` line: 
    `..
    s.sendline('hash')
    s.expect('.*Hash mark printing.*')
    interact = 1
    while interact == 1:
        human = raw_input()
        #crashes here
        if human == '`':
            interact = 0
            break
        else:
            s.sendline(human)
            s.wait()
            s.expect('ftp> ')`

Comment: @baconpancakes: So you want to interact with the FTP session after you connect?

Comment: @DavidCullen yes, that's right.

Comment: or at least be able to get something like subprocess.check_output() to return the result of downloading/uploading a file..

Comment: @baconpancakes: Where did you get `passiveftp`?

Comment: @DavidCullen it's from a colleague, so i can't see how it works.. i thought it would be simpler to work with it, but maybe it might better to start from scratch and learn more about passive mode..

Comment: You should probably have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/3657941

Comment: @DavidCullen it looks like the same thread from earlier by lit. the problem with 3rd party programs is that there's a concern when working with confidential devices that connect to the server. for example speedtest.net can't be used because it pulls information about connected devices.

Comment: Have a look at the Python [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html). It has support for [PASV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_pasv).