# Copy from FTP server to a network server with Windows cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I want to make a batch file to copy files from an FTP server (external) to a network drive.

I am not sure which command to use.

That will be for a batch file on Windows 10

Many thanks.

Comment: How about the `ftp` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Windows `ftp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp):

```
ftp -s:download.txt
```

Where the `download.txt` may look like:

```
open ftp.example.com
username
password
get /remote/path/file.txt \\localserver\share\path\file.txt
bye
```

---

Though Windows `ftp.exe` does not support passive mode FTP, what makes it useless nowadays in lot of scenarios due to ubiquitous firewalls and NATs.

If you face a problem with this, you will have to use a 3rd party FTP client (see [How to use passive FTP mode in Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/850848)) or some more powerful scripting language than a batch file (e.g. PowerShell).