# ftp transfer fails with "500 Illegal PORT command."

Tags: linux, ftp

I am trying to create a script that uploads a .wav file after processing to a linux FTP server (utilizing vsftpd).

The script looks as follows:

```
@echo off

echo user anonymous> ftpcmd.dat
echo >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\%1 %1>> ftpcmd.dat
REM echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat 194.26.183.194
del ftpcmd.dat
```

My vsftpd.conf:

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=ftp
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES
```

```
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
```

Have both been tryed with param. "NO" combined and seperated

With this result:

```
Gewartet wird 0 Sekunden. Weiter mit beliebiger Taste...
Verbindung mit 194.26.183.194 wurde hergestellt.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
200 Always in UTF8 mode.
ftp> user anonymous
331 Please specify the password.

230 Login successful.
ftp> put C:\Users\Anwender\Downloads\Anwender_DESKTOP-V30SJ8P_2021-09-07-15-07-12.wav Anwender_DESKTOP-V30SJ8P_2021-09-07-15-07-12.wav
500 Illegal PORT command.
425 Use PORT or PASV first.
ftp>
```

I have a hard time understanding what I am supposed to do and would be very thankful for any hints regarding further steps.

Comment: Why do you keep removing the "windows" keyword? Your problem is *unique* to **Windows** `ftp`. Order `ftp` implementation support the passive mode. + Why did you unaccept my answer? Is there anything unclear?

Comment: I changed some stuuff back to how it was before your edit, as you added stuff to the post you assumed. Stuff like "windows command line" etc is not true as the problem existes not only for command line but for ftp clients like filezilla and other ftp services as well. The probolem is somewhere in my server conf (on linux) not in windows.

I unmarked the answer as the most helpfull part (beeing the "-d" in my case) is rather hidden within "useless" info

Dont get me wrong, iam thankfull for the help, but your answer was much more helpfull  before editing it

Comment: All other FTP clients, except the Windows `ftp`, would default to the passive mode, so you will not get the *"500 Illegal PORT command"* error with them. Of course, you might have additional server-side problems that prevented even other clients from working. But server-side problems are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Only your local Windows `ftp` script problem is something you can ask here. Rest belongs to [su] or [sf]. After all, that's why your question was closed. If you keep the question the way you have it – closed and with no accepted answer – your question will get automatically deleted

Answer (score 1):

You are probably connecting to a server in a different network (through a firewall or a NAT).

So `ftp.exe` sends a local network address in the `PORT` command, which the server cannot connect back to. That's why it reports `Illegal PORT command`. You can check the address, if you add `-d` switch to `cmd.exe` commandline.

If you believe that the server can connect to that local network address, you can set `port_promiscuous=YES` in `vsftpd.conf`.

If the server cannot indeed connect to the address, there's not much you can do. With a modern FTP client, the solution would be to use the passive mode. But Windows `ftp.exe` does not support it. You have to use a 3rd party client. See [How to use passive FTP mode in Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643542/850848)