# Getting "Too many parameters for command", when calling WinSCP command-line from VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ftp, winscp

[Upload file via FTP from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737691/upload-file-via-ftp-from-excel-vba/32004195#32004195) was very helpfull, I'm using the code to synchronize a local folder to my FTP server.

```
Call Shell( _
     CurrentProject.Path & "\WinSCP.com /log=" & CurrentProject.Path & "\ftp.log /command " & _
     """open ftp://user:pass@ftp.server.com/"" " & _
     """synchronize local " & localfolder & " /www/remotefolder/wines -filemask=""*.png"" " & _
     """exit""")
```

I'm trying to issue an `exit` command at the end, but the code gives me a

> Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'.

The line in the log tells me

```
synchronize local C:\localfolder\wines /www/remotefolder/wines -filemask=*.png exit
```

The `exit` is in the same line as the `synchronize` one, when I use the put script this doesn't happen. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing closing quote after the `synchronize` command. And the quotes around `-filemask` value have to be doubled. Or actually, you do not need them, as the value does not contain spaces.

This will do:

```
   """synchronize local " & localfolder & " /www/remotefolder/wines -filemask=*.png""" & _
```

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax

---

The symbol you have at the beginning of `—hostkey` and `—rawsettings` is not a simple [hyphen-minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) (`-`), but [em-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) (`—`).

Please use hyphen-minus (`-`) — what is the dash that you find on the standard English [and other] keyboards.

*So actually you have the very same problem as in [WinSCP forum post you referred to](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15981).*

---

Or even easier, have [WinSCP GUI generate a script template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

Also see FAQ [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

---

*Other questions with the same error message, but different problem:*

- *[WinSCP command line - Too many parameters for command 'open' when using -rawtransfersettings switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55696465/850848)*
- *[WinSCP "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249680/850848)*
- *[FTP "Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'" with WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964436/850848)*

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, worked as I want it.  Love your work on WinSCP!