# WinSCP command line - Too many parameters for command 'open' when using -rawtransfersettings switch

Tags: command-line, sftp, winscp

I am getting "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error when trying to connect to a server for below command,

```
option confirm off 
open sftp://uname:pwd@abc.example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" -timeout=60 -rawsettings SendBuf=0 SshSimple=1 -rawtransfersettings IgnorePermErrors=0 PreserveTimeDirs=0
```

I have checked lot of other posts mentioning the use of Double-Quotes for text having space and I think my above script is complaint with that. 
If I remove the last set of parameters followed by `-rawtransfersettings` my script work fine. That is the `open sftp://uname:pwd@abc.example.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx" -timeout=60 -rawsettings SendBuf=0 SshSimple=1` commands works perfectly.

I am not sure how to proceed further with this as I am new to command scripting world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP `open` command has no `-rawtransfersettings` switch.

That switch belongs to file transfer commands, like `get`, `put`, etc.

---

*Other questions with the same error message, but different problem:*

- *[WinSCP "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249680/850848)*
- *[Getting "Too many parameters for command", when calling WinSCP command-line from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47865865/850848)*
- *[FTP "Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'" with WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964436/850848)*