# FTP "Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'" with WinSCP

Tags: ftp, winscp

Trying to automate FTP through the WinSCP script:

```
option block abort
option confirm off
open ftp://[link to cloud server here]
synchronize local (path to local files) /Qty Update
exit
```

Session starts and connects but then I get

> Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'

Answer (score 0):

If the paths contain spaces, you have to [surround them by double-quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes):

```
synchronize local "C:\path to local files" "/Qty Update"
```

---

*Side note: It's [`option batch abort`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#batch), not `block`.*

---

*Other questions with the same error message, but different problem:*

- *[WinSCP command line - Too many parameters for command 'open' when using -rawtransfersettings switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55696465/850848)*
- *[WinSCP "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59249680/850848)*
- *[Getting "Too many parameters for command", when calling WinSCP command-line from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47865865/850848)*