# WinSCP "Too many parameters for command 'open'." error

Tags: batch-file, ssh, command-line, sftp, winscp

I am trying to connect to an SFTP with the following command to move all .csv files from one location to another and I'm getting the *"Too many parameters for command 'open'."* error.

```
option echo off
option batch on
option confirm off
open sftp://XXX@XXX.com/ —hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" —rawsettings ProxyMethod=3 ProxyHost=proxy.uk.XXX.com
cd /XX/XX/XX/IN/LOAD
lcd \\XX.local\EMEA\XX\XX\Import_Location
put *.csv -nopreservetime=on -nopermissions=on
exit
```

I added the `—hostkey` parameter due to the *"The server's host key was not found in the cache"* error, the batch file was working fine before that, but I want to correct the host key error.

I checked all the [dashes](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15981), the quotes, the only thing I'm confused about is whether the hostkey parameter is correct. The information online on [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey) and some forums says you have to use SHA-256 fingerprint of the host key only which is a different format to the MD5 detail `XX:XX:XX:XX....` Please can you help which one it is?

```
—hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
```

OR

```
—hostkey="ssh-rsa 2056 AbC50IDzyx.....="
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55696465/winscp-command-line-too-many-parameters-for-command-open-when-using-rawtran) is a similar query to mine, but I cannot see what the difference is so that theirs works and mine doesn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol you have at the beginning of `—hostkey` and `—rawsettings` is not a simple [hyphen-minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/index.htm) (`-`), but [em-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) (`—`).

Please use hyphen-minus (`-`) – what is the dash that you find on the standard English [and other] keyboards.

Or even easier, have [WinSCP GUI generate a script template for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

---

*So actually you have the very same problem as in [WinSCP forum post you referred to](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15981).*

---

*Other questions with the same error message, but different problem:*

- *[WinSCP command line - Too many parameters for command 'open' when using -rawtransfersettings switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55696465/850848)*
- *[Getting "Too many parameters for command", when calling WinSCP command-line from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47865865/850848)*
- *[FTP "Too many parameters for command 'synchronize'" with WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964436/850848)*

Comment: Once he said he'd already checked that I didn't bring it up, thought it was only in the example code accidentally, but the more I Think about it the more likely that's the issue.  I thought the issue was he didn't know what the hostkey was or how to obtain it, - which was the Q he asked, but I think you are probably right, so thats my upvote ot you.

Comment: Oh, so sorry, I've completely misread the forums about dashes. I had the normal hyphens and then changed them all to em-dashes... Thank you, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining the correct hostkey fingerprint:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey