# Upload file through vba and WinSCP.com

Tags: vba, excel, winscp

I don't know what is happeining since it's just flashing by the screen. But I have this code in vba.

```
Shell "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\WinSCP.com /script=H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\script.txt"
```

In script.txt i have:

```
open ftpes://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.SERVER.nu
put H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\lista.txt /Avvikelser/lista.txt
close
```

As I have understood it I need ftpes to make it passive?

I can't even start WinSCP from cmd prompt
[image]

I need to use a cmd style solution as I can't install software on the computer.
The file is not uploaded when the script ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WinSCP.COM** is only an console interface program for **WinSCP.EXE**, you need to have both in the same directory.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/executables